# CodeIgniter: Librariy class not loading with this code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and following one Nettuts premium tutorial how to build CMS in codeigniter.

Very first my **application** and **system** directories lies on different path out of public_html and set path in config.php file.

I have created two files Frontend_Controller.php and Admin_Controller.php and within those files created class as below.

**application/My_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $data = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['errors'] = array();
        $this->data['site_name'] = config_item('site_name');
    }
}
```

**libraries/Frontend_Controller.php**

```
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**libraries/Admin_Controller.php**

```
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to autoload above classes by writing an __autoload() function into config.php file but it doesn't load the files/classes

**config.php**

```
function __autoload($classname)
{
    if(strpos($classname, 'CI_' !== 0))
    {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';

        if(file_exists($file) && is_file($file))
        {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand and resolve the issue... Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not using CI's autoload? why are you loading classes inside config??

Comment: Oh! I am not so much aware with it. Can you please learn me how to do it?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It's pretty good, I'm sure it will answer your questions. As a personal advice, you should always read a framework/library doc before using it...

Comment: Yeah I have read the document and need to define in autoload.php but I am still confuse how to write the class name and where? Since I am having controller class in libraries also having capitalized text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with codeigniter autoload in `application/config/autoload.php` file
like this :

```
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`
```

for details see here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/autoloader.html

You can also try with this one:

The snippets below look at the following locations for lowercase filenames: core/ libraries/ models/

```
function __autoload($class) 
{
  $path = array('core', 'libraries', 'models');

  if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
    foreach($path as $dir) {
      if (file_exists(APPPATH.$dir.'/'.strtolower($class).'.php'))
        include_once(APPPATH.$dir.'/'.strtolower($class).'.php');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. one query with this.. when I use `$autoload['libraries']` how can I write `Frontend_Controller` into the array? `array('frontend')` is that right?

Comment: Frontend_Controller is not a library I guess...You don't autoload Controllers!

Comment: That is my own class of file.. Please refer in my question.. So how can I load that class? CI may be nice but it is very confusing to understand, at least for beginners like me.. :(

Comment: Take a look here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: take a look here also : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/libraries.html